# How to get just the image URL and not the content from google_images_download?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to develop a discord bot, and when I receive a particular keyword from discord, I search for it using google_images_download. And later I want to return a random image url that came from the search result.

```
response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()
arguments = {"keywords":"yuzu figure skater","limit":10,"print_urls":True} #creating list of arguments
paths = response.download(arguments)   #passing the arguments to the function
```

However, doing this downloads the images. But I just want the url associated with the images. Not the images themselves.

I am new to using google_images_download. Any pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `"no_download": True` to your arguments.  A full list of the possible arguments can be found [here](https://google-images-download.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arguments.html):

```
arguments = {"keywords":"yuzu figure skater","limit":10,"print_urls":True, "no_download": True}
```